# public key certificate decryption in emv

Tags: encryption, certificate, emv

I want to decrypt Public Key Certificate using a CA Public Key, 
how can i get the output as below.

Recovered Data:                6A02457896FF12170314EF01019001E04E4FC478A42241068E2C9CFDEE9D7450F48F812FA66CEFB8ECBE31DD3C26C3B8A3891B77C1AA2A5A7448B869B7213D36C341E9B71302ADF478F67537032C080186C44034B1801D7644B6EEFAEA566D7336A8C83F42B7992F28BF5EA6B9D14C05870AD4DBD8CDAB8771F65F83D800B353B11E1805C7E4529F261C16A38DE756BC

Data Header:                   6A

Data Format:                   02

Issuer Identifier:             457896FF

Certificate Expiration Date:           1217

Certificate Serial Number:         0314EF

Hash Algorithm Indicator:          01

Issuer Public Key Algorithm Indicator:     01

Issuer Public Key Length:          90

Issuer Public Key Exponent Length:     01

Issuer Public Key:             E04E4FC478A42241068E2C9CFDEE9D7450F48F812FA66CEFB8ECBE31DD3C26C3B8A3891B77C1AA2A5A7448B869B7213D36C341E9B71302ADF478F67537032C080186C44034B1801D7644B6EEFAEA566D7336A8C83F42B7992F28BF5EA6B9D14C05870AD4DBD8CDAB8771F65F

Hash Result:                   83D800B353B11E1805C7E4529F261C16A38DE756

Data Trailer:                  BC

Comment: You might want to have a look at [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader)

Answer (score 1):

Download EMVCo Book 2, and read section 5 and 6.

Here you are trying to open an Issuer Public Key Certificate. Issuer Public Key certificate is opened using the Certification Authority Public Key. This key is located using RID and Index. You can find most [here](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/243-ca-public-keys)

Once CAPK is decided you have to use RSA reversible algorithm as mentioned in Annex B Approved Cryptographic Algorithms B2 Asymmetric Algorithms.

Comment: i have gone through the same but  do you have the code to decrypt the certificate by passing the Public key.

Comment: that code is in java and i am working in c. sorry but i am not getting that code

Comment: Ideally the document should be sufficient. I have done it once. But don't have that code now. Just try to get the logic from the jvmreader code.

Comment: can you please help me with this decryption, i  am not getting it after reading also

Comment: src/main/java/sasc/util/Util.java check this code in javaemvreader perform Rsa function